# How do I set distance to annotation in tableview?

Tags: mkmapview, distance

I have an app that fetches web data and stores it in CD-db.  So far, FirstViewController (MKMapView) fetches CD-db into NSMutableArray and uses its values to plot locations by getting the array of custom objects from the db.  I cycle thru a for loop while creating the annotation (pin).  Each pin gets its distance property set from a calculation I use for the distance from userLocation to each pin.

This app runs in a tabbarcontroller and the other tab is a tableview listing of these locations.  I get the values for that tableview by fetching the CD-db and getting the array's values at cellForRowAtIndexPath method and putting the values into the cell.textLabel etc...

My question is, since the distances from userLocation to each pin are calculated on the mapview controller, how do I get those distances on the tableview controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the mapview controller as the tableview's datasource. That way only one viewcontroller fetches data. Once you build the mapview controller's array of custom objects it can be used to respond to all the tableview datasource calls such as cellForRowAtIndexpath and numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: Ok, so I create a FirstViewController *fVC = alloc. Then in SecondViewController say self.datasource = fVC. Then how do I set tableview's cell.textLabel? Using fVC.storesArray?

Comment: You'll want to look at the http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html. In there is a function called `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` which will be called on the datasource (fVC). It should make up a cell (or reuse an existing one) and set the textLabel by checking the indexPath and using it as the position in the array e.g. `cell.textLabel = array[pathIndex.row]`.

Comment: Ive used tableviews before and set their datasource and delegate to the current view controller, but ive never set a mapviewcontroller as the datasource for a tableview.

Comment: a datasource doesn't need to be the currentviewcontroller, or any veiwcontroller for that matter. So long as it implements the protocol it can be anything. That's the beauty of a protocol.

Comment: ok i understand that. Im just not seeing how it would work.  (1)I would make my mapVC adopt the UITableViewDataSource protocol. (2)Then I import MapVC.h into TableVC. (3)Instantiate MapVC in TableVC and get its NSMutableArray property?

Comment: The thing is, the distance to userLocation is not in the db.  So its not in the array gotten from the CDdb either.  Its only calculate when I plot the MKAnnotations and I add it as part of my Model object, MyLocation.distance.  Where can I paste the code?

Comment: Assuming the mapVC gets made first and it then creates the tableVC and pushes it on to the screen then you should easily be able to get the tableVC's tableview from the mapVC and become its datasoure e.g. `newTableVC.tableView.datasource = self`. Then in mapVC's  `cellForRowAtIndex` you get the item out of your array using the `indexPath` that the tableview wants and you can get the distance from your current location to the item using CLLocation's `distanceFromLocation` I think.

Comment: Ok it's a tabbarcontroller app so both the mapVC and the tablrVC get instantiated at the start.  So I could set the data source in the appdelegate?

Comment: You could, you could also subclass your tabbarcontroller and set the delegates in there. I did exactly that last night. Discussion getting kind of long now, you'll need to ask a new question if you want that explained.

Comment: Ok here is the post, thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14490689/how-do-i-subclass-a-uitabbarcontroller-using-storyboards

Comment: Ok I think I got what you were saying, I implemented datasource and delegate protocol in mapVC. Set the datasource of tableVC (in MyTabBarController class) to mapVC. But I have 2 problems: `cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];` gives an error saying tableview property not found in mapVC && that im using a uisearch bar so i have `if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) in numberOfRowsInSection` and `[filteredResultsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` in cellForRow...where its undeclared identifier. How should I handle that?

Comment: You should be using the UITableView that is passed in a parameter to those functions. i.e. `[tableview deque....` not `[self.tableview deque....`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23346/discussion-between-marciokoko-and-craig)