# How do I subclass a UITabbarcontroller using storyboards?

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, subclass

I have a tabbar application using storyboards.  Tab 1 is a UIViewController with Mapview & Tab 2 is a UITableViewController.

The appdelegate calls for a web fetch (via a custom class) and takes that web response and pareses it (via a custom class) and then puts the info in a CD-db (via a custom class).

MapVC fetches results from the CD-db and populates an NSMutableArray (property) to be looped thru.  The array contains a custom CD-db object with 2 coordinates which are used to create an MKAnnotation in the for loop.  The distance from each MKAnnotation to userLocation is calculated and the MyLocation Class object is completed with a distance value in its subtitle property.  Thus each pin on the map displays a title (name) & subtitle (distance).

TableVC creates a separate fetch to the CD-db and populates its array property to be used in the cellForRowAtIndexPath (CFRAIP).

Now I want the tableview to also display the distance in each cell.  So it has been suggested I subclass the uitabbarcontroller and set the delegate/datasource of the TableVC.tableview to the MapVC.  My question is, how do I subclass my uitabbarcontroller and set the delegate and datasource?

Something like: in app delegate get the window's rootviewcontroller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to subclass UITabBarController. Make a new file in Xcode, set UITabBarController as the parent class.

Then go to your storyboard and select the tabbarcontroller, set its custom class to the class you just make.

In `viewDidLoad` of the tabVC get its sub VC's and find the ones you want. Here's the pseudo code, I can tidy it up later:

```
CSMapListViewController *mapListViewController;
CSTableViewController *tableViewController;

for (UIViewController *vc in self.viewControllers)
{
    if ([vc isKindOfClass:[CSMapListViewController class]])
    {
        mapListViewController = (CSMapListViewController *)vc;
    } else if ([vc isKindOfClass:[CSTableViewController class]])
    {
        tableViewController = (CSTableViewController *)vc;
    } 
}

tableViewController.tableview.datasource = mapListViewController;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks so much, but how does this give me access to MyLocation objects created in FirstViewController?  The MyLocation objects are created when the user taps the 'Plot' button.

Comment: What is trying to access the mylocation objects? The mapviewcontroller? They're right there. The tableVC.tableview? It will ask it's `datasource`, which is the mapVC which has the location array. The tableVC? Well it doesn't have direct access right now, but you'd use the same technique as above to get hold of both VCs and join them as you see fit. I'd invent a tableVCDelegate and define the methods the delegate must have (e.g. `getLocations`) and then assign the mapVC as the delegate and implement that method.

Comment: mapVC plots MyLocation objects on a mapView. I need to display each MyLocation.distance property in the tableview. Now that the datasource for tableVC.tableview is mapVC. My cFRAIP is `StoreLocation *location = [mapVC.locationArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.nameLabel.text = MyLocation.name;
        cell.distanceLabel.text = MyLocation.distance;` This wont work because StoreLocation objects have lat and long and name etc. The mapVC.locationArray has StoreLocation objects in it. But MyLocation is an MKAnnotation object made from each StoreLocation's lat and long property.

Comment: You've veered off onto something else now. If you want to know how to fill in a UITableViewCell from your MyLocation class you'll need to ask a new question. It keeps this question clean and helps people who the same UITableViewCell problem find your question and solution.

Comment: Agreed, so I moved it here again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14441368/how-do-i-set-distance-to-annotation-in-tableview

Comment: I suggest you post the code from your cellForRowAtIndexPath along with your MyLocation class header (or enough detail to know what attributes it has) in a question asking how to populate the fields. You'll also need to outline what you want in the distance label (or subtitle & title labels)

Comment: Ok here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514377/how-to-setup-a-mapviewcontroller-as-datasource-to-a-tableviewcontroller-for-disp